# String refusing to be stated when it has already been initiated and assigned

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to take in the user's rock, paper, scissor choice (which is entered as either r, p , or s), but when I try to change and call it, it gives me an error.

Here is my code:

```
package labs10;

import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class RPSRunner
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String full;
        String response;
        String player = "";

        out.print("Select [R,P,S] :: ");
        response = kb.next();
        if (response.equals("R")) {
            full = "Rock";
        } else if (response.equals("P")) {
            full = "Paper";
        } else if (response.equals("S")) {
            full = "Scissors";
        }
        out.println("Player chooses " + full);

        RockPaperScissors game = new RockPaperScissors();   
        game.setPlayers(response);
        game.determineWinner();
        out.println(game);
    }
}
```

and my error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
    The local variable full may not have been initialized
        at labs10.RPSRunner.main(RPSRunner.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String full;
```

You declare `full` with no initial value. If the user types `R`, `P`, or `S` you assign it a value. But what if they type something else? Then `full` will still be uninitialized. The compiler doesn't like that.

Either assign it a value initially...

```
String full = null;
```

...or add a final `else` clause to handle all other user input.

```
if (response.equals("R")) {
    full = "Rock";
} else if (response.equals("P")) {
    full = "Paper";
} else if (response.equals("S")) {
    full = "Scissors";
} else {
    full = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `response` is neither "R", "P" or "S", `full` won't be initialized at the point you try to print it with `out.println("Player chooses " + full);`.

You must assign a default value to it in this case (or throw an exception).

Comment: I tried making initializing it to String response = "R"; , so then the user could change it, but that didn't fix it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Grant How? Simply changing `String full;` to `String full=null;` will eliminate your compilation error. Having a default value for `response` doesn't help, since the use may enter an invalid value later. It's the `full` variable that must have a default value.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't understand at first!